# Integration By Parts stuck

Tags: integration

Given this S-L problem with solution:

[image]

[image]

And I want to prove this equality when $f(x)$ also has the same conditions as S-L problem.

[image]

I tried doing integration by parts on the left side twice but didn't end anywhere.. But I know it's the way to solve it.. any help?

Comment: But what **did** you get after integrating by parts?

Comment: @You'reInMyEye 0=0

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Integration by parts yields:
$$\int_0^\pi f''(x)v_n(x)dx=$$ $$v_n(\pi)f'(\pi)-v'_n(\pi)f(\pi)-v_n(0)f'(0)+v'_n(0)f(0)-\lambda_n\int_0^\pi f(x)v_n(x)dx $$

(Kindly see my answer [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1397100/integration-by-parts-question-integrate-x3ex/1397150#1397150) for a quick way to integrate by parts).

Since $f(x)$ has the same conditions as $v(x)$, then the first four terms cancel out, leaving you with the desired result.

Comment: Just one question, This what I'm getting: $v_n(\pi)f'(\pi)-v'_n(\pi)f(\pi)-v_n(0)f'(0)+v'_n(0)f(0)+\int_0^\pi f(x)v_n(x)dx$ How are you getting this $\lambda$ ?

Comment: The differential equation. You should get $v_n''(x)$ in that last integral, that you then replace by $-\lambda v_n$

Comment: Thank you, I got this the whole  time though -,- :(