# Integration of a function.

Tags: calculus, indefinite-integrals

Can we  integrate a function without using the ILATE rule? For instance, $$\int (2x+9x^2)\sin 4x \cos x\,dx.$$ Can I integrate it without using ILATE in a quicker time? Because when ILATE rule is followed, it gets into a loop.

Answer (score 4):

First, I think you need to simplify the $\sin(4x)\cos(x)$ using the following:

$$\sin(a)\cos(b)=\frac 12\left(\sin(a+b)+\sin(a-b)\right)$$
$$\sin(4x)\cos(x)=\frac 12 \left(\sin(5x)+\sin(3x)\right)$$

Expanding $\frac 12(2x+9x^2) \left(\sin(5x)+\sin(3x)\right)$ makes applying the ILATE rule (using integration by parts tables) pretty straightforward.

Comment: Is there any other method other than ILATE?

Comment: @ManishBhatt This is a rather simple case involving only algebraic and trigonometric functions, so any other method would make things much more complicated. A way to integrate by parts a lot faster is using the table in this answer http://math.stackexchange.com/q/1397150

Comment: Okay fine.Thank you !